# loaded iframe is not recognized

Tags: jquery, iframe

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#somediv').load('chapter.php');
var a = $('#vplayer').width();
alert (a);
});
```

this is inside `chapter.php:`

```
<iframe class='viframe' id='vplayer' src='//www.youtube.com/embed/XotSjeW0uos?rel=0'></iframe>
```

Alert appears but result is `NULL`.

All others elements are measured correctly.

Comment: What do you mean `result is NULL`?

Comment: @TheWobbuffet, inside the alert is written just one word - `NULL`

Comment: Weird, for me it alerts `300`... do you have jQuery included?

Comment: @TheWobbuffet, hm, I tried just now again - `null`. Of course I have jq included, otherwise nothing would be displayed. All others elements (div for example) are measured correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5p7SR/

Comment: @TheWobbuffet, in your example iframe IS NOT LOADED USING JQUERY ! It must be in another file !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for it to load:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#somediv').load('chapter.php', function()
    {
        var a = $('#vplayer').width();
        alert (a); 
    });
});
```

Comment: The Wobbuffet, thanks, it works now, but does it mean that `document.ready` function does not do it's job ?

Comment: @bonaca `document.ready` waits for the document to load before it executes the code, so it *is* doing its job, but you're loading *new* html, take a note of that.